# Err.Number not populating for 'Excel Ran Out of Resources' error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I've developed a program using Excel VBA which occasionally causes an 'Excel Ran Out of Resources' error.

Closing the file, reopening, and rerunning the macro always fixes whatever issue created the error.  I know that preventing the error in the first place is best practice, but am resigned to believe that it's unavoidable.

So, I would like to alert the user of the error, instead of Excel doing it, and perform some actions once the error has been detected.  The problem is that I can't get VBA to recognize the error using the `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` routine or the `Err.Number` property.  I never get to the msgbox below:

My code is as follows:

```
Sub test()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Calculate

ProcedureDone:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error", vbOKOnly, "Oops"
    Resume ProcedureDone

End Sub
```

Any insight would be fantastic since I've been searching for several days and haven't been able to find a work around.

Comment: I don't think `On Error` captures memory issues. Could you update your question with the `Calculate` procedure as it might help with establishing the issue.

Comment: Specifically, what error is coming up from excel? Also when is this code being called? Is this in an event, EG: inside a 'Workbook_Open' event that's being ran?

Comment: The error is "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas.  As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated."

Comment: The code is being called in a general module, not inside an event.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Instead of `Calculate` it's really `ActiveSheet.Calculate`.  It's really that simple.  Any idea if it's possible to determine which formulas in the worksheet are causing the error?  I don't have any array formulas but do have some that feed directly into some pivot tables using variables and the indirect function.

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to run across [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496888/does-excel-have-vba-for-on-alert-like-it-does-for-on-error) that sounds like yours.

The point from the other thread is that Excel does not treat these *application method* results as *VBA errors*. Rather, they are *Excel alerts*, and they can be suppressed but not trapped in VBA as errors.

The way I interpret this is that when you execute certain application methods from VBA, it does not raise errors that VBA can trap. Rather, Excel interacts with the user as if the user had issued a GUI command. On the other hand, if an application method is designed to interact with VBA (e.g., if it returns a value), then VBA might be able to handle its errors.

This is distinct from the way VBA handles *worksheet functions* rather than application methods. VBA can intercept errors raised by worksheet functions, as noted in "Error Handling With Worksheet Functions" [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CallingWorksheetFunctionsInVBA.aspx).

I realize this does not solve your problem, but it gives you an idea of why.