# Does Excel have VBA for "On Alert" like it does for "On Error"?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, alert, pivot-table

I have found out that a box popping up in relation to a pivottable is in fact an "alert" box as opposed to an "error" box.  Does Excel have any kind of "On Alert GoTo :" like it does for "On Error GoTo :"???

I can disable the alert completely, but then I fail to warn users when they enter an incorrect name that isn't found on the pivottable. This also reassigns things and I don't want that!

Comment: You could do a check for every `Worksheet_Change` and output your error message if it is not like you want it...

Comment: I'm trying to think of how I could implement that....
Is there a good "check" for seeing if the name they enter is one of the names on a pivottable?

Comment: You could loop the names... I need to check it at my pc... but there should be someone who gives a solution to this faster then me... however, check this question again as soon as possible...

Comment: Problem solved, used a loop to check the names against the names in the pivottable.  Then assigned a variable a result.  If the result was 1, an "If" statement executes the entire block of my program.  If the result was 0 (meaning it didn't find the name on the pivottable), then it pops up a message saying to change the name and exits the sub.

Comment: Doing it by yourself ist always the best solution :)

Comment: Thank you sir! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Preventing the Alert by Data Validation**

One way to ensure that a user supplies a name from a predefined list is to use [Excel's built-in data validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211485). You can have a cell provide its own drop-down list of choices that are based on a dynamic range.  You can set this up from Excel's data tab and/or by [using VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821214.aspx). The reference is "dynamic" because, if the reference range changes, the drop-down list will change with it, and if the reference range is a column of a table, then the list will grow and shrink according to that column.

The action to take if validation fails can be customized as well, including an entry message and error message. One option when using VBA is to disable any action and instead use the validation's `Value` property to determine action at runtime. Validation is triggered before a cell value is changed, so my guess is that it will proceed the alert your seeing.

---

**Errors vs Alerts (Can we work with an event?)**
In regard to the more general question about if there is an `On Error` equivalent for alert messages, I don't think there is. VBA doesn't have stellar error handling to begin with. `On Error` handles runtime errors before message box display, not on a display event, and I don't think there are any VBA readily accessible events caused by message box display.

**Errors vs Alerts (Can we work with an object?)**
It sounds like you found `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, and I think that's about as much as you can do with alerts. As the OP mentions, it would be nice to turn of alerts but still programatically check them. You can do this with errors by using the `Err` object, but I don't think you can do it with alerts if there's no alert object.

Comment: I failed to mention that my list is a master list of everyone in the company, but the only valid names that can be entered are from departments, which I do not receive a list of those names.  I have to infer the names via some very roundabout methods, which in turn come from a pivottable.  I could possibly do what you say and make a dynamic range from a pivottable???

For now, the method I used is working to check whether the "names" appear on the pivottable and if not, exits the sub.  :)